# PHP fetching array inside an array

Tags: php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getCropsInvestor)){
        $cropID = $row['CropID'];
        $selectCrop = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Crops WHERE ID=$cropID");
        $fetchCropData = mysqli_fetch_array($selectCropData,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if($fetchCropData){
            echo 'Suc';
        }
        else{
            echo 'Fail';
        }
        $checkAvail = $fetchCropData['Availability'];
```

Can someone explain to me why this code returns Fail 
and a solution on how to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query result stored in `$selectCrop`.

`$selectCropData` should be  `$selectCrop`.

`$fetchCropData = mysqli_fetch_array($selectCrop,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`..

Comment: oh damn how can i be so dense. i didn't even notice that. i though fetching array inside a fetch is unavailable. thank you for this. i'll accept this after 10 mins

Comment: I would suggest you to use `JOIN`s if possible.

Answer (score 0):

When Query Executed

```
$selectCrop = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Crops WHERE ID=$cropID");
```

this result is stored in `$selectCrop`
so use 
`$selectCrop` instead of  `$selectCropData` in `mysqli_fetch_array`

```
$fetchCropData = mysqli_fetch_array(**$selectCrop**,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Thats all ....
Happy coding

Comment: I suggest yo to use PDO to handle these errors better